# Should The Last Ship Prequel be watched before The Last Ship series?

Tags: the-last-ship

Was thinking of watching [The Last Ship](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2402207/) and I notice on IMDB there is also [The Last Ship Prequel: Dr Scott’s Video Journal](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4497794/).

It’s a set of six 2 minute videos, which apparently I can watch on YouTube. They appear to have been released before the series. Are these supposed to be watched before the series proper?

Comment: I’m not asking for a recommendation. I don’t care whether it’s good or not. I’m asking whether it should be watched before the series, chronologically speaking.

Comment: The way you worded it made it look like a recommendation question, but the edit has made it much clearer. I've voted to keep this open, and hopefully the close-votes and downvotes will get reversed.

Comment: Yep, I see that, thanks. Glad the edit makes it clearer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The short answer is Not Necessary because you will get the theme of series in first few episodes.

But now that I have seen prequel for very first time after watching this series 3 years back, I would say that there are no spoilers. Instead this prequel is sort of introduction and offers cliffhangers.

So go ahead.

Also, am amazed to see Coronavirus at [0:16](https://youtu.be/iwpViY8-WnU?list=PLrfiiKH6_BkGivIQLfEFsREjoc5eSB7hG&t=16%20?)